Whether there are probability measures in infinite-dimensional Spaces such that foliations are finite-dimensional, the Fubini's theorem holds?
The infinite dimensional space here could be Hilbert space.Which books about foliation theories do you recommend to read to learn more

Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.
